# Error displaying the error page

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, nginx

So I'm attempting to install Joomla on a lemp stack, ubuntu 16.04, php7. I use the same lemp stack for Wordpress sites all the time no hassle. I unzipped the Joomla files into my /html/ directory and I'm getting the above error. It doesn't tell me a lot.

When I googled it I found a lot of people getting the same error with a few extra lines that seemed to be related to the database however as I haven't even got to the Joomla install page to give it the database username and password I find it unlikely to be the problem.

Folder/File permissions are set to 755/644 respectively and everything is chown -R www-data:www-data. If I replace index.php with the following it works fine

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error message? It may be due to Nginx configuration file.

Comment: The error message is "Error displaying the error page"

Comment: This isn't the full error message. The full error message should have at least one colon (`:`). Try to read the error logs or set `display_errors` etc in your `php.ini` file. Some hints can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327466/how-to-enable-error-reporting-in-nginx-php-config).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it would probably be best off asked at SuperUser or ServerFault